# What is this hanging plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents, hanging-plant

The leaves of this plant are bit thick & filled as of any succulent plant. 
I have not seen any flower from 6 months, maybe it don't bloom.

It likes hanging.

Here are its picture:

 
Full View:

 
[image]

Leaf View - 1:

 
[image]

Leaf View - 2:

 
[image]

Leaf View - 3:

 
[image]

It looks like some variety of Pilea; May be [Pilea depressa](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Pilea%20depressa&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=e8dNUdb_IcHXrQeUkoCYCQ&biw=1280&bih=613&sei=f8dNUdjmPIelrQeV9YDYCA#um=1&hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=Pilea%20depressa&oq=Pilea%20depressa&gs_l=img.12..0j0i24l4.35509.35509.8.36365.1.1.0.0.0.0.105.105.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.7.img.4SWTXCBTqUo&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.bmk&fp=8aa46cbbcf6b7855&biw=1280&bih=613&imgrc=Sj8iBL6xsQRmjM:;tIoBHtBv-4-fdM;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.gheesung.com%252F_%252Frsrc%252F1320657618024%252Fplants%252Ffoliage-plants%252Fpilea%252Fpilea-depressa%252FPilea.Depressa02.JPG%253Fheight%253D400%2526width%253D300;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.gheesung.com%252Fplants%252Ffoliage-plants%252Fpilea%252Fpilea-depressa;300;400).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd hazard an educated guess that this is [*Sedum spurium*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedum_spurium) of some variety - planted in the ground, it sprawls across it, so planted in a hanging container, it would grow like this The shape of the leaves strongly suggest it, along with the notched edges, coupled with the fact it is obviously a succulent. Note that Sedum is an extremely large and varied group of plants, all commonly referred to as Stonecrop.

Comment: Yes, it could be a variety of Sedum (as per Google images & Wikipedia), however no exact match found.

Comment: Me too - but there are well over 5,000 varieties...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree, it's some sedum.
If you haven't flowers, it is why your plant hasn't sun enough. That's also why it has so few leaves and so long branches.
I don't know in english. In italian it's said they make "files". It happens to every plant put indoor, with few light.

Try to get some cutting (it's very easy, you can get it from any piece of branch or from leaves too) and plant it in plain air and sun. It should grow thicker. You can classify your plant from its normal form (after good sun exposition) and from flowers.